# FLANN matcher in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

In openCV 3.1.0 when i give cv2.flann_Index it says cv2 has no attribute called flann_index. Has this function changed in opencv 3? I am using python3 and looked up the documentation online but they were all dead ends.
code :

```
class Codebook(object):
    def __init__(self, hdffile):
        clusterf = tables.open_file(hdffile)
        self._clusters = np.array(clusterf.get_node('/clusters'))
        clusterf.close()

        self._clusterids = np.array(range(0, self._clusters.shape[0]), dtype=np.int)
        self.n_clusters = self._clusters.shape[0]

        self._flann = cv2.flann_Index(self._clusters,
                                      dict(algorithm=FLANN_INDEX_COMPOSITE,
                                           distance=FLANN_DIST_L2,
                                           iterations=10,
                                           branching=16,
                                           trees=50))
```

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: sorry for not adding, it has been updated

Comment: In OpenCV 3.3, it's ok to load "cv2.flann_Index"